# Get call stack for warning in ILogger (ASP.NET Core 2.0)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to get call stack inside Log method of `ILogger` interface?

```
void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter);
```

My production code raises a few warnings(entity framework), but I am having a hard time to found sources, so I thought it would be nice if I could log file/class/method which raise the warning.

Some of the warnings:

> The LINQ expression '{expression}' could not be translated and will be
> evaluated locally.
>
> Query: '{queryModel}' uses a row limiting operation (Skip/Take)
> without OrderBy which may lead to unpredictable results.

I know what they mean, but I am unable to found which code (in my huge application) raises them.

Comment: do you want to log only method/file/class warnings ? not the debugging level logs?

Comment: No. I want to log what is defined in `appsettings.json`, usually warnings and up. With error I get exception and with exception stack trace so it is easy to correct code. But frameworks (like EF) raises warnings, but I need to know where in order to fix them.